# Can I Call SQL Developer PL/SQL Formatting From a Stored Procedure

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, code-formatting

In Oracle SQL Developer when I right click an object of type Function, Procedure, or Package I have an option in the context menu to 'Run' or 'Profile'. The dialogue brings up fields for 'Target', 'Parameters', and 'PL/SQL Block'. 
The 'PL/SQL Block' displays a sample code snippet to run the program written as an anonymous block, and it is formatted.

My question: How is this built, and can I put a procedure around it so that I can call it from the database?

If possible, I would need the parameter list (object name, owner, ??) for calling the executable/jave/etc. 
I would then create something like this:

```
create procedure pretty_print_sample_code(...some parameter list needed by developer method..) is
begin
    ..do some checks
    ..invoke the developer code
    ..output result as clob or line by line the result
end pretty_print_sample_code;
/
```

Then from sqlplus or developer I could run the program to get my result. This could be useful for new functionality documentation (including code snippets within tech specs) or simply having a way to get a 'template' within the database so I can easily change parameter values and execute.

I'm primarily an Oracle developer (6 yrs self taught) with minimal working knowledge of Java or C# or the like, so if this can't be invoked easily via a stored procedure, then no need for a response to go into great detail.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I read your question again and I can't tell if you are actually wanting JUST to call our code formatter or not, see my answer and reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We interrogate the data dictionary to get the data we need to paint a dialog like this:

[image]

You can see the SQL we run behind the scenes to get this data, then we just dynamically generate the code you see in the anonymous block.

For example, we run this to get a list of arguments for your package procedure:

```
SELECT position,
       argument_name,
       data_level,
       data_type,
       in_out,
       CASE
              WHEN char_used = 'C' THEN
                     char_length
              ELSE
                     data_length
       END data_length,
       data_precision,
       data_scale,
       type_owner,
       type_name,
       type_subname,
       pls_type
  FROM sys.dba_arguments
 WHERE owner = :owner
   AND object_id          = :id
   AND object_name        = :name
   AND nvl(overload, '0') = :overload
 ORDER BY sequence
```

When you click 'OK' we run that through our Script Engine, which can handle just about anything SQLPlus can...and that includes capturing SERVEROUTPUT like DBMS_OUTPUT buffer contents.

You can quickly see the SQL we're running through the JDBC connection to Oracle in the Log Panel...the rest is OUR Java code, and for you to reproduce through whatever.

Comment: Right, I assumed there was logic to interrogate dba_arguments and possibly dba_procedures - at least that was my going in approach to develop the 1st of a 2 part solution. The 2nd piece would be once I have a block built dynamically, then how do I format it. So when I saw that SQL Developer had something that did both already, I was hopeful that perhaps there was a way I could simply write a wrapper procedure which called whatever method or built in dbms* like package that is used behind the curtain to both write the sample and format it and pass it back either as an object/lob or output.

Comment: yeah, it's part SQL and part Java.

we have a command line interface to format a buffer or file, it's called SQLcl, and has a FORMAT command.